# Table breaking after adding header

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add `thead` in tables in which it's already not there. Only if `th` element is present and `th's` parent should be `tr`.

After running code then the table first row is breaking in the browser:

```
$(".node table").addClass('sticky-header');

var all_tables = $(".node table").filter(function() {
  return !$(this).find('thead').length && $(this).find('th').length;
  //add header if no thead is there but a th must be present
});

all_tables.each(function() {
  var parent = $($(this).find('th')[0]).parent();

  if (parent.is('tr')) {
    parent.css('border', '5px solid red');
    //wrap the in thead
    parent.wrap('<thead>   </thead>');
  } else {
    //skip this table
  }
});
```

What could be the problem? I can see that unnecessary `tbody` is also being added

The original table looks like:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="sticky-header">
  <tr>
    <th> State Name</th>
    <th> Local Customer Care Number</th>
  <tr>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> Madhya Pradesh &amp; Chhattisgarh</td>
      <td> 0755 4448080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Uttar Pradesh</td>
      <td> 0522 4448080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Karnataka</td>
      <td> 080 44448080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Andhra Pradesh</td>
      <td> 040 44448080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Mumbai</td>
      <td> 022 44448080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Maharashtra</td>
      <td> 020 44448080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Himachal Pradesh</td>
      <td> 08628048080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Assam</td>
      <td> 08133848080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Jammu &amp; Kashmir</td>
      <td> 09596748080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Bihar &amp; Jharkhand</td>
      <td> 09955148080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> WB</td>
      <td> 033 44448080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Delhi</td>
      <td> 011 44448080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Tamil Nadu</td>
      <td> 044 44448080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Kerala</td>
      <td> 0484 4448080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Noth East</td>
      <td> 08132948080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Haryana</td>
      <td> 0124 4448080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Gujarat</td>
      <td> 079 44448080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Rajasthan</td>
      <td> 0141 4448080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Orissa</td>
      <td> 07077448080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Punjab</td>
      <td> 0172 4448080</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

### Rendered Output

[image]

### Rendered HTML

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="sticky-header">
  <tbody>
    <thead>
      <tr style="border: 5px solid red;">
        <th> State Name</th>
        <th> Local Customer Care Number</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody><tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> Madhya Pradesh &amp; Chhattisgarh</td>
      <td> 0755 4448080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Uttar Pradesh</td>
      <td> 0522 4448080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Karnataka</td>
      <td> 080 44448080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Andhra Pradesh</td>
      <td> 040 44448080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Mumbai</td>
      <td> 022 44448080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Maharashtra</td>
      <td> 020 44448080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Himachal Pradesh</td>
      <td> 08628048080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Assam</td>
      <td> 08133848080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Jammu &amp; Kashmir</td>
      <td> 09596748080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Bihar &amp; Jharkhand</td>
      <td> 09955148080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> WB</td>
      <td> 033 44448080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Delhi</td>
      <td> 011 44448080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Tamil Nadu</td>
      <td> 044 44448080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Kerala</td>
      <td> 0484 4448080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Noth East</td>
      <td> 08132948080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Haryana</td>
      <td> 0124 4448080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Gujarat</td>
      <td> 079 44448080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Rajasthan</td>
      <td> 0141 4448080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Orissa</td>
      <td> 07077448080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Punjab</td>
      <td> 0172 4448080</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What does the rendered html look like? (You can check this using your browser's developer tools)

Answer (score 0):

i think you shold check this line

```
  return  !$(this).find('thead').length && $(this).find('th').length;
```

from what i could understand this should be

```
  return  !$(this).find('thead').length && !$(this).find('th').length;
```

its the only thing i can see unusual from the first look

Comment: I've pasted the html

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see your HTML to be sure but I think `thead` is being applied more than once. Take a look at the [manual for jQuery's wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function.

Using the example straight from the manual with this HTML structure:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

If you call `wrap` on the document object with a class of `container` you actually end up with this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="new">
    <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  </div>
  <div class="new">
    <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice how `wrap` works on every HTML object found inside the parent you called `wrap` on. I think each `tr` or `td` is being wrapped with an additional `thead` causing your error.

I think what your looking for is the [wrapAll function](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/).

**UPDATE:**
Now that we have your HTML I'm pretty confident that each of your `th` are being wrapped in a `thead` like so:

```
<tr>
  <thead>
    <th>State Name</th>
  </thead>
  <thead>
    <th>Local Customer Care Number</th>
  </thead>
</tr>
```

Replace

```
parent.wrap('<thead>   </thead>');
```

with this code

```
parent.wrapAll('<thead>   </thead>');
```

If this doesn't work your grabbing the wrong parent element. Based on your HTML `wrap` will never work for you. Don't forget to review the manual pages I linked earlier. Also, I think `'<thead>   </thead>'` is wrong, from what I can make of the manual you should only need `'<thead>'` and it will auto close for you. I don't use jQuery so I can't help much more than this.

Comment: i've pasted the html

Comment: @user5858 Look at my update now especially the very end about possibly not using the closing thead: </thead>

Answer (score 0):

Actually browser is automatically adding `tbody` tag. So this `thead` is landing within `tbody` then Chrome is adding another `tbody` for the rest of rows. So finally 2 `tbody's`

I just added this line after  `parent.wrap` and it's working fine:

```
parent.parent().prependTo($(this));
```